# Faild on deployment on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

I made an app with node.js +react  but I can't deploy it on heroku.
It work on localal host
I tried to delete package-lock.json file but it doesn't help.

here is my scripts in package.json in server directory

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

and my heroku logs

> *
>
> ```
> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Creating runtime environment
>
>        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>        NODE_ENV=production
>        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
>        NODE_VERBOSE=false
>
> -----> Installing binaries
>        engines.node (package.json):  8.1.1
>        engines.npm (package.json):   5.0.3
>
>        Resolving node version 8.1.1...
>        Downloading and installing node 8.1.1...
>        npm 5.0.3 already installed with node
>
> -----> Restoring cache
>        - node_modules
>
> -----> Installing dependencies
>        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>        added 93 packages in 7.456s
>
> -----> Build
>        Running heroku-postbuild
>
>        > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864
>        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
>
>
>        > fsevents@1.2.9 install /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
>        > node install
>
>
>        > fsevents@1.2.9 install /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
>        > node install
>
>
>        > core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
>        > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
>
>        > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
>        > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
>        added 1550 packages in 43.208s
>
>        > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client
>        > react-scripts build
>         /tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/deep-equal.js:17
>     options = { prototype: true, ...options };
>                                  ^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_52aeb2bcb298df1839239655d0215864/client/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/index.js:9:19)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:513:17) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
> ```
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0
>   build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of
>   this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /tmp/npmcache.1V3q7/_logs/2019-06-21T10_03_50_779Z-debug.log npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! server@1.0.0
>   heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix
>   client && npm run build --prefix client` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /tmp/npmcache.1V3q7/_logs/2019-06-21T10_03_50_793Z-debug.log
>       -----> Build failed
>
> ```
>        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>
>        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>        https://help.heroku.com/
>
>        Love,
>        Heroku
>          !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed*
> ```

Comment: Update your node version to at least 8.6.0 to support use of the spread operator for object literals - See supported versions [here](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties-object-spread-properties)

Answer (score -1):

You do not required to delete the package.json file. You just have to upload all the files and folder excepting node_modules. Heroku server install all required packages for you.

One more thing, you have to add "test" command under the scripts tag.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
 },
```

Comment: Although these may be further issues, the error shown is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` which is due to the use of the spread operator for object literals. This is not supported in the node version used (8.1.1)

Comment: Try to remove everything from the script tag and just place test and script command. So you may get idea that from where actually problem occurs. Thanks